# Proper way to use Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, dry

This is a simple accordion made by jQuery's `animate()` method.

```
var accordionTrigger1 = $('h4.panel-title.category_men'),
    accordionTarget1 = $(accordionTrigger1).parent().next('.panel-body');

$(accordionTarget1).hide();

$(accordionTrigger1).on('click', function() {
    $(accordionTarget1)
    .stop()
    .animate(
    {
        height: 'toggle'
    }, 
    {
        duration: 300,
        easing: 'easeOutCirc'
    }
    );
});
```

Suppose I have to create more accordions, I am now creating new variables for the trigger and its target and for that I am repeating the click function again and again. Is there a way by which i can use the following function without having to write the `animate()` method over and over again (ie not repeating the function and calling it up by a parameter or something)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are asking something like this:

```
var accordionTrigger1 = $('h4.panel-title.category_men'),
    accordionTarget1 = $(accordionTrigger1).parent().next('.panel-body');


accordion(accordionTrigger1, accordionTarget1);



function accordion(trigger, target){
    target.hide();

    trigger.on('click', function() {
        target
            .stop()
            .animate(
                {
                    height: 'toggle'
                },
                {
                    duration: 300,
                    easing: 'easeOutCirc'
                }
            );
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello Mike.. thanks for the prompt reply. I did not understand what `accordion(accordionTrigger1, accordionTarget1);` is doing.. kindly explain

Comment: Hey Anuj, It is hiding the target and binding the click to the trigger. You can call this function with other triggers/targets.

Comment: okay i think i got it.. You created a function called 'accordion' and passed two arguments which you are referencing to later... is that so?

Comment: True, I thought that is what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

In your first line place `more selectors` separated by commas.

```
var accordionTrigger1 = $('h4.panel-title.category_men, more selectors, more selectors, ...'),
```

Not the phrase `more selectors`. Actual selectors. :)

Comment: A little humor rarely hurts.